# Three.js/React-Three-Fiber: Property X does not exist on type Object3D<Event>

Tags: typescript, three.js, react-three-fiber

I'm using **React Three Fiber** with **TypeScript** to type my React App. I have the following code:

```js
return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
      <scene name="Scene" {...props}>
        <mesh
          ref={mesh}
          scale={1.5}
          name="Object_0"
          morphTargetDictionary={nodes.Object_0.morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={nodes.Object_0.morphTargetInfluences}
          rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
          geometry={nodes.Object_0.geometry}
          material={materials.Material_0_COLOR_0}
        />
      </scene>
    </group>
  );
```

But I'm having the same error all the time: `Property: 'morphTargetDictionary' does not exist on type 'Object3D<Event>`, and the same occurs with *morphTargetInfluences* and *geometry*.

I have tried to do the following because I understand that I need to include those properties inside the declaration of the `Object3D` (I'm using the npm package `@types/three`), but with no results.

```js
declare module '@types/three' {
  export default interface Object3D {
    morphTargetDictionary: number;
    morphTargetInfluences: number
    geometry: string
  }
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the solution, you need to use [assertions](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to tell Typescript **the type of the value** that you are using:

```js
return (
    <group ref={group} dispose={null}>
      <scene name="Scene" {...props}>
        <mesh
          ref={mesh}
          scale={1.5}
          name="Object_0"
          morphTargetDictionary={(nodes.Object_0 as THREE.Mesh).morphTargetDictionary}
          morphTargetInfluences={(nodes.Object_0 as THREE.Mesh).morphTargetInfluences}
          rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]}
          geometry={(nodes.Object_0 as THREE.Mesh).geometry}
          material={materials.Material_0_COLOR_0}
        />
      </scene>
    </group>
  );
```

That's because `THREE.Mesh` extends from `Object3D` which is a class that has `morphTargetDictionary` as a class attribute.